# How do I send data and a string for discord bot?

Tags: json

```
if(args[0] != undefined){
     var SendThing = JSON.stringify(args[0], " was not An Imposter!")
     message.channel.send(SendThing)
}
```

How do I make it so it's like ";eject Person", "Person was not An Imposter!" without it just saying things like "NaN" or ""Person""?

Comment: That's not how JSON.stringify works...what is `args[0]` in this context? An object? A string? We need more details to help, or this will probably be closed.

Comment: I used stringify to test it and it didn’t work, so I just went here. I’m new, and “args[0]” is a string. I just want to combine the two so I can post “args[0]” and “ was not An Imposter,” in the same measage.

Comment: You can use `+` to join strings together: `args[0] + " was not An Imposter!"` JSON.stringify is not for joining strings, it's for converting JSON to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I was told by someone in the comments to do:

```
if(args[0] != undefined){
      message.channel.send(args[0] + " was not An Imposter!")
}else{
      message.channel.send("Name someone to eject!")
}
```

instead of what I tried, this works, and I'm sorry for asking such a dumb question.

Comment: @AngryPlayyer - that's okay, we are all learning. You'll get better! I remember when I used to ask questions like that...it actually wasn't too long ago, now that I think of it.